# An exception occured while executing 'INSERT INTO Pagetemplates... Concrete5

Tags: exception, mamp, concrete5

I'm trying to build some websites localy with MAMP and Concrete5 but when i want to add a page template to my theme, C5 shows me this error what's going on i'm trying to follow this video:https://www.concrete5.org/documentation/developers/5.7/designing-for-concrete5/building-a-concrete5-theme/converting-an-html-template-to-a-concrete5-theme/
It seems to me that I'm the first one having this problem can someone help me out?

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO PageTemplates
>   (pTemplateHandle, pTemplateIcon, pTemplateName, pTemplateIsInternal,
>   pkgID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["full", "full.png",
>   "Full", 0, 0]: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062
>   Duplicate entry 'full' for key 'pTemplateHandle'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys I found the solution. The problem was that I changed the name of my html doc into full.php but as the .html file extension is hidden on my pc I couldn't figure it actually still was an html doc. I had to change the doc-type somewhere else. Weird it didn't even ask if I wanted to change the doc but anyways that's the solution hopefully someone with the same problem will figure it more quickly as me now haha.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's trying to recreate the full page template over top of an existing entry. Try deleting the current full page template (/dashboard/pages/templates), then try adding a page or re-adding the page full page template. Not sure why it'd be doing that.